# Parsing JSON array causes error: unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON data which I am trying to parse, but my code is not working. I get the error

> unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR).

The array structure looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [mautic.lead_post_save_update] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lead] => Array
                        (
                            [isPublished] => 1
                            [dateAdded] => 2016-09-15T08:08:20+00:00
                            [createdBy] => 1
                            [createdByUser] => Deepak Tiwari
                            [dateModified] => 2016-12-20T14:20:36+00:00
                            [modifiedBy] => 1
                            [modifiedByUser] => Deepak Tiwari
                            [id] => 149269
                            [points] => 100
                            [color] => 
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [core] => Array
                                        (
                                            [compulsation] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 39
                                                    [label] => Job 
                                                    [alias] => compulsation
                                                    [type] => text
                                                    [group] => core
                                                    [field_order] => 2
                                                    [object] => lead
                                                    [value] => 0
```

and so on. I need to access the value of "job compultion". The code I am using is:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data=json_decode($json,TRUE);
$job=data->mautic.lead_post_save_update->0->lead->fields->core->compulsation->value;
```

I am not getting any value in `$job`.

Comment: Access the arrays using `[]` operator instead of `->`

Comment: it's an array not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using object property syntax (`->`) to access array elements, which won't work. Your code should use array syntax (`[...]`), like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data=json_decode($json,TRUE);
$job=data['mautic.lead_post_save_update'][0]['lead']['fields']['core']['compulsation']['value'];
```

That's what the error message is trying to tell you. A decent IDE, like PHPStorm (no affiliation), would help you catch errors like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! , it worked.I am wondering why -> is not working , where I have other code in which I am using -> to access

Comment: @DeepakTiwari `->` is the correct syntax if you are accessing a property of an *object*. If you have an *array*, which is what your `print_r()` output above shows that you have, then you must use brackets (`[` and `]`).

Comment: thank you. I am new to php. Thanks for saving my life. I  was trying  this from last 15-20 hours

Answer (score 0):

Your json_decode() is not creating a object. Its an array and you can get your variables by using [] instead of the ->

Comment: $job=$data['mautic.lead_post_save_update'][0]['Lead']['fields']['core']['compulsation']['value'];

Comment: $job=$data[0][0][0][10][0][0][7];  I tried accessing it by changing , but still not have any value